# How to setup a Solr backup to S3 in 8.10 version

Tags: amazon-s3, solr, backup

I’m, new in solr so let me know in case I’m missing anything here.
I’m following this guide but no luck so far - https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_10/making-and-restoring-backups.html

So, what I’ve done at the moment
In `solr.xml` I’ve added a backup section

```
<backup>
    <repository name="s3" class="org.apache.solr.s3.S3BackupRepository" default="false">
      <str name="s3.bucket.name">solr-backups</str>
      <str name="s3.region">us-east-1</str>
    </repository>
  </backup>
```

After that, I’ve added the S3 plugin (via ansible as I do with the rest of the things usually)

```
- name: Copy SOLR S3 module to server
  copy:
    src: /opt/solr/dist/solr-s3-repository-8.10.1.jar
    dest: /opt/solr/server/solr/lib
    owner: solr
    group: solr
    remote_src: yes
  become_user: root
```

And finally, Added S3 Credentials to solr config

```
- name: Add aws credentials
  become_user: root
  lineinfile:
    path: /opt/solr/bin/solr.in.sh
    line: 'SOLR_OPTS="-Daws.accessKeyId=REDACTED -Daws.secretAccessKey=REDACTED"'
```

After restarting Solr to have all new settings applied I'm running the following command to do a backup.

```
http://my-server.com:8983/solr/schools/replication?command=backup&name=29-10-2021&repository=s3&location=backupfolder
```

But receiving the following error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/core/backup/repository/BackupRepository
URI:    /solr/schools/replication
STATUS: 500
MESSAGE:    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/core/backup/repository/BackupRepository
SERVLET:    default
CAUSED BY:  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/core/backup/repository/BackupRepository
CAUSED BY:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.core.backup.repository.BackupRepository
```

[Error message for solar backup on s3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPDYg.png)

Any idea what might be wrong with my config?

Comment: What does the `BACKUPSTATUS` (request with `command=details`) outputs?

Comment: @GaëlJ - I've updated the description of the problem since was able to proceed further with my backup configuration. Please check the description and let me know if there is anything else I can provide to help investigate this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to copy in all of the jars from the `contrib/s3-repository/lib` folder in addition to the plugin jar from `dist/`